# Using Map with @ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am trying to use a map for `@ResponseBody` annotation and the xml response isn't produced using the Spring's xml message converter. It throws `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` while generating the response. I am using Spring 3.2.

Whereas the json response is generated without any exception. I used MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter for json response.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/reqPath/{params}", 
                            produces={"application/xml","application/json"})
public Map<String, SomeObject> getDataAsXmlOrJson() {
......
}
```

Comment: What kind of HTTP headers does the incoming HTTP request have?

Comment: None, the default Accept header `application/xml` is taken by Spring.

Answer (score -1):

You have to register http message convertor for XML. You can use jaxb or for more controlled environment you can create custom convertor.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail? I am already using jaxb `XmlRootElement` annotation but it works only for `Object` and not `Map<String, Object>`